# Find out the number of days overlapping between two date ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with a date range. I would like to find out if it overlaps another range and calculate the number of days overlapped.

Trying to do it in just mysql without going through loops in PHP which is the front end language.

```
id | start_date | end_date
1  | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-07
2  | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-03
3  | 2019-01-06 | 2019-01-09
```

Date Range `start = 2019-01-04`, Date range `end = 2019-01-07`

With the dates being in the `format YYYY-MM-DD`

Would like the end result being :

```
id | start_date | end_date    | total_days
1  | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-07  | 4
2  | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-03  | 0
3  | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-09  | 3
```

Comment: Why should the start_date of the 3rd row within the result be `2019-01-05` instead of `2019-01-06`?

Comment: Try something with `GREATEST(start_date, start_range)` and `LEAST(end_date, end_range)` and `DATEDIFF`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use MySQL DATEDIFF() function:

> MySQL DATEDIFF() returns the number of days between two dates or
>   datetimes. This function only calculates the date portion from each
>   expression.

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2);
```

[Click here to find examples](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php)